# Inverse image of codomain

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

Is it true that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous function then $f^{-1}[Y] = X$ ?

I suppose that it is true and I try prove it:

Suppose that $f^{-1}[Y] \neq X$ so exsists $x$ such that $ x \in f^{-1}[Y]$ and $x \not\in X$. So we have that $f(x) \in Y$ and $x \not\in X$ but $f: X \rightarrow Y$ so we have conflict. But I have not use fact, that $f$ is continuous. My proof is wrong? Or maybe for any $f: X \rightarrow Y$ we have $f^{-1}[Y] = X$ ?

Comment: This is always true, as we have $f(x)\in Y$ for any $x\in X$.

Comment: Yes, it is true for any $f$. Your proof is only half complete, as you have only showed $f^{-1}(Y)\subseteq X$.

Answer (score 6):

This is true regardless of continuity. $f$ being a function from $X$ to $Y$ just says it is a special subset of $X \times Y$: namely such that for every $x \in X$ there is a a unique $y \in Y$ such that $(x,y) \in f$ and this unique $y$ is then also denoted $f(x)$.

Now $f^{-1}[A]$, where $A \subset Y$, *by definition* equals the set $\{x \in X: f(x) \in A\}$. As by definition of a function from $X$ to $Y$ *every* $f(x)$ is in $Y$, $f^{-1}[Y] = X$. This is just a consequence of the definitions, nothing more.